# IndexOutOfRangeException in C# – Why has length of array become 0?

Tags: c#, arrays, null, variable-assignment, indexoutofrangeexception

I have a piece of code in C# that populates an array with values. In the `Awake` method I set the length of the `values` array, yet when I try to access it in the  `setSample` method it returns an IndexOutOfRangeException. The

```
public int gridSize = 32;
public int width;
public int height;
public int featureSize = 32;
public float[] values;

public void Awake () {

    width = gridSize;
    height = gridSize;
    float[] values = new float[6 * width * height];
    Debug.Log("Array length: " + values.Length);

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y += featureSize) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x += featureSize) {
            setSample(x, y, Random.value);
        }
    }
}

public void setSample (int x, int y, float value) {
    Debug.Log("Array length: " + values.Length);
    values[((x & (width - 1)) + (y & (height - 1)) * gridSize)] = value;
}
```

I added the `Debug.Log()` lines, which gave me the following output:

*Array length: 6144*
*Array length: 0*
*IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.*

Both the methods and the variables are public, so I don't see why there should be any access issues. Why does the array change after I declare it? Is it because it is full of null values?

Comment: BTW *Is it because it is full of null values* is not the case - when you initialize the array it will be filled with the default of the type - which for `float` is 0 and not null

Comment: You have defined a local variable named `values` as same as in the class. So you get `null object reference error` in `setSample()` not `index out of range exception. With what values of `x` and `y` in `setSample()` you get `index out of range error`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of declaring again you should use existing **`values`**, inside the awake method.

change

**From**

```
 float[] values = new float[6 * width * height];
```

**to**

```
values = new float[6 * width * height];
```

Comment: Using existing `values` removes `null object reference error`, but original error is `index out of range`